# "addinstallusertogroupexception_desc" Oracle 12C installation error

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I'm trying to install Oracle 12C on my Windows 10(Home) 64-bit laptop but I'm getting this "addinstallusertogroupexception_desc" error message in the middle of installation. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

Just close the error window that popped up and the installation will go through fine. Don't select the options in the popup screen.

Answer (score 1):

Just cancel the popup menu ,n number of times then it will work

Answer (score 0):

Install Oracle JDK first then Oracle database setup.
Choose latest version of Oracle JDK file.